# SQLCipher security

Tags: java, android, sqlcipher

How exactly SQLCipher for Android Application works?
http://sqlcipher.net/design/

As i understood it all depends on PRAGMA key and this key should be saved on app, maybe in binary.

However this is insecure as alomst everyone could decompile .apk file on rooted phone.
Maybe i missed something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, securing the key is the tricky part.  Ideally it's (partly) supplied by a password the user enters when signing on to the app, but that isn't always ideal, so sometimes you have to resort to the much-maligned "security by obscurity" approach and assemble the key from bits and pieces stashed here and there.

Comment: Well i released that there isn't 100 % secure solution to save sensitive data. I can't let for user to enter key because i want to hide that data from user it self. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

> As i understood it all depends on PRAGMA key and this key should be saved on app, maybe in binary.

No.

> Maybe i missed something ?

The key comes from the user, in the form of a passphrase that the user types in. In SQLCipher for Android, this passphrase is passed to methods like `getReadableDatabase()` on the revised version of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLCipher team universally recommends against embedding a fixed key in an application binary. No matter how creative an application is about obscuring an embedded key, a sufficiently determined attacker will be able to extract it from the application package and open a database.

Unfortunately some applications still choose to use SQLCipher with embedded keys as a rudimentary form of DRM, i.e. by making it difficult for casual users to view data. However, this does not provide any substantial amount of security.

If you need to protect sensitive data the best approach is to use a key derived from a strong passphrase entered by the user. SQLCipher provides strong key derivation automatically, so all you need to do is provide the user passphrase through PRAGMA key or one of the equivalent keying mechanisms provided in SQLCipher wrapper libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I generate key form secureRandom and then save key on KeyStore (BKS).
For KeyStore i generate password using: random, user info, device info and  password.